# SQL Server Management Studio Code (SSMS) Code Outlining

Tags: sql-server, ssms, outlining

I have an intermittent problem with SSMS. Sometimes (as I write this, actually), code outlining is gone in my SSMS.  That means there are no + and - signs to expand/collapse sections of code.

[image]

Wonder if any one else has had this issue and solved it

Comment: Show the end of that statement? This happens if the statement is not valid..

Answer (score 3):

Found it.  I had disabled Intellisense since it (sometimes) conflicts with SQL Prompt.  Re-enabling Intellisense brought outlining back